# How to render the blade templates of Lavacharts?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I am new to this package: [khill/lavacharts](https://packalyst.com/index.php/packages/package/khill/lavacharts). So I try to test some of their examples on their documentation.

On the example of [BarChart](http://lavacharts.com/#examples) we can see these codes:

```
$lava = new Lavacharts; // See note below for Laravel

$votes  = $lava->DataTable();

$votes->addStringColumn('Food Poll')
      ->addNumberColumn('Votes')
      ->addRow(['Tacos',  rand(1000,5000)])
      ->addRow(['Salad',  rand(1000,5000)])
      ->addRow(['Pizza',  rand(1000,5000)])
      ->addRow(['Apples', rand(1000,5000)])
      ->addRow(['Fish',   rand(1000,5000)]);

$lava->BarChart('Votes', $votes);

return view('sample', compact(['lava'])); // I add these line
```

---

I try to render the **BarChart** in the view:

**Method 1**

```
@barchart('Food Poll', 'poll_div')
```

No render happened / no BarChart. It just display *@barchart('Food Poll', 'poll_div')* on my view.

**Method 2**

```
{!! Lava::render('BarChart', 'Food Poll', 'poll_div') !!}
```

or

```
{!! $lava->render('BarChart', 'Food Poll', 'poll_div') !!}
```

It displays me an error:

> BarChart('Food Poll') was not found.

---

Someone knows how to render the BarChart in view?

Comment: You're calling the BarChart `Votes` and not `Food Poll`....

Comment: @CaddyDZ I just follow the documentation. Hmm can you show me the proper way to do that?

Comment: Do you have a <div id="poll_div"></div> in your html?

Comment: @charles yeah thats in their doc

Comment: @CaddyDZ yeah your right. I forgot to put `<div id="poll_div"></div>`, you should put that in answer so that I could marked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the `BarCharts` by appropriate name

```html
{!! $lava->render('BarChart', 'Votes', 'poll_div') !!}
```

And make sure to have a div where to render the charts in your HTMl

```html
<div id="poll_div"></div>
```

Hope this helps